# Jmeter variable value unchanged during loop

Tags: jmeter

```
-Thread group (from Here I'd like to control number of threads/loops)
  -config stuff headers, directory listing, other vars creation
  -Simple controller
    -POST request
      -extract Location portion from response using re called "test_id"
    -While controller ${__javaScript("${status}" != "DONE",)}
      -GET using "test_id"
        -timer
        -extract "status" using re from response body
```

The idea behind is that I'd like to sent POST and keep GETting until I receive certain value in response. All the POSTs result in unique point to GET to. I would like to keep thread number limited but enable a lot of loops. I imagine that next loop starts when the previous GET "status" is DONE.

So the issue is that I am unable to use loops with current setup. First time the "status" gets to DONE it then start sending all the remaining POSTs and no more GETS. Debug sampler shows status value as DONE for all the GETs although POST have different test_id. I have tried moving while to the level of simple sampler bit its the same. Threads working fine though. Do I misinterpret the loops within the jmeter or is it obvious flaw in here?
Appreciate your insight and help

Answer (score 0):

You need to **reset** the variable before doing the POST because when your thread (virtual user) starts the second/third/next loop the `status` variable is equal to `DONE` therefore While Controller doesn't do its job as the condition is not met.

You can add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) after the While Controller (or before the POST request) and put the following code there:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()
vars.put('status', 'not done')
```

Where:

- the first line executes [SampleResult.setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function so the sampler will not be present in listeners and .jtl results files
- the second line sets `${status}` variable value to `not done` (`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance) so this way you will get confidence that the While Controller's children will be executed at least once

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: Work as expected now. Thanks a lot!